# How to prove $\frac{\sin(\pi+\alpha)}{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)} + \frac{\cos(\alpha-\pi)}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)+1} = \frac{1}{\cos\alpha}$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove this identity?

> $$\frac{\sin(\pi+\alpha)}{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)} + \frac{\cos(\alpha-\pi)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)+1} = \frac{1}{\cos\alpha}$$

I took it from exercise about reduction, so it is possibly involved.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/pdf/trig.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(\pi+\alpha)}{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)} + \frac{\cos(\alpha-\pi)}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)+1} = \frac{1}{\cos\alpha}$$

$\sin(\pi+\alpha)=-\sin \alpha$

$\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)=-\cos \alpha$

$\cos(\alpha-\pi)=\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos \alpha$

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)=-\sin \alpha$

Then $$\frac{\sin(\pi+\alpha)}{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)} + \frac{\cos(\alpha-\pi)}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)+1} =\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha} - \frac{\cos\alpha}{1-\sin \alpha} =$$
$$=\frac{\sin \alpha-\sin^2 \alpha-\cos^2\alpha}{(1-\sin \alpha) \cos \alpha}=$$
$$=-\frac{1-\sin \alpha}{(1-\sin \alpha) \cos \alpha}= -\frac{1}{\cos\alpha}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$
\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)=-\cos\alpha
$,

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)=-\sin\alpha$,

$
\sin(\pi+\alpha)=-\sin\alpha
$,

$
\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha
$

Answer (score 0):

Ideas for you to use:

$$\sin(\pi+a)=\sin\pi\cos a+\sin a\cos\pi=-\sin a$$

$$\cos(a-\pi)=\cos a\cos\pi+\sin a\sin\pi=-\cos a$$

Or in general:

$$\sin(x\pm y)=\sin x\cos y\pm\sin y\cos x$$

$$\cos(x\pm y)=\cos x\cos y\mp\sin x\sin y$$

Comment: IMO you don't have to say $\sin(\pi+a)=\sin\pi\cos a+\sin a\cos\pi=-\sin a$ you could just say $\sin(\pi+a)=-\sin a$ without using the formula, since that is a bit more advanced.